# Automated disk monitoring: what is my system doing already, what more should I do?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, disk, monitoring, smart

Does an Ubuntu 14.04 server automatically perform smartctl condition monitoring? How can I check that it's happening properly? How can I be sure that I will receive an email when things start to go wrong?

If the answer to the first question is 'no', what is a recommended simple, straightforward way to set this running in the Ubuntu context?

Have smartctl setup defaults changed in newer LTS releases?

This is *not a duplicate* of [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1): the output from `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` does not say when the last test was completed, and gives no information about the scheduling of regular SMART tests.

I am trying to find out what **regular, scheduled** testing is happening on my machine, to ensure if a problem arises, I can be confident it will be spotted by the system and reported.

SMART testing is one thing, but perhaps there are other things that I can  be using as well?

Comment: Don't think smartmontools is installed by default. As an admin of the system, you should install and configure it.

Comment: I don't think there are any regular tests scheduled by default. I doubt there will be - that's for the admin to setup and configure.

Comment: The whole point of SMART is that you don't need to run tests actively but the drive monitors its status continuously and the operating system can probe the current status at its leisure and then notify someone of out-of-range values. The latter part is was `smartctl` does or can be set up to do.

Comment: **I'm voting to reopen this question because the linked question does not explain how to survey and report the SMART status continuously.**

Comment: @DavidFoerster he's asking a lot of questions in one question and the answer to all his questions are "none, it's not done automatically" the question needs a lot more editing before re-opening IMHO, so I voted to keep closed...